# How to swap subreports in report dynamically

Tags: grails, groovy, jasper-reports

I am working on grails and using jasper report to generate pdf,docx . I am using ireport to make it.I make many sub report within main report. My requirement is to swap sub report dynamically. 
here are my three sub report.

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="91" width="200" height="24"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfInstance})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/report/showInterest.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="115" width="200" height="27"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfInstance})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/report/showWorkExperience.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="142" width="200" height="31"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfInstance})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/report/showEducation.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

my controller code code is here, which help to generate a jasper report into pdf format.

```
def testTemplateFileForDownload = {
    def result = [:]
    result.data = []

    result.data << [key1:value1,key2:value2]
    params._format = "PDF"
    params._file = "tamplate9" // set your file name this will call to sample.jrxml
    def report = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, request.getLocale(), result)
    generateReport(report)
}

def generateReport = { reportDef ->
        if (!reportDef.fileFormat.inline && !reportDef.parameters._inline) {

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"${reportDef.parameters._name ?: reportDef.name}.${reportDef.fileFormat.extension}\"");
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "${reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp}");
            response.contentType = reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp
            response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
            response.outputStream << reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray()
        } else {
            render(text: reportDef.contentStream, contentType: reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp, encoding: reportDef.parameters.encoding ? reportDef.parameters.encoding : 'UTF-8');
        }
}
```

Now I want to swap these 3 sub report in any order in my pdf. I have no idea how to do for this.

and also I have one more question.
I have a domain class. there are some field in that class.For demo

```
class Demo{
String field1
String field2
String field3
}
```

I am sending a instance of this class in ireport.

```
Demo demo = Demo.findbyid(1)
```

then how can I get value of all fields, field1,field2, and field3. One way I know that I can send in map one by one. Like

```
result.data= [field1:demo.field1,field2:demo.field2]
```

And I can get value on ireport to define field of same name. Is there any idea that how can I get value from its instance.

Comment: It is a bad idea to join two different questions in one post

Comment: Both are related to ireport. So I do not think that this is join of two question.

Comment: There are a lot of questions related to *Java* on *SO*. But as you can see there are more than 400K questions marked with *Java* tag, not the one huge ;)

Comment: Thanks alex for your suggetion , I will take care about this next time. But now can you please give me answer of my question. I am really in deep shit because of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a parameter to pass in the report Name (or even the whole path)  in you **subreportExpression** should help with you first question.  I have even had may main report pass this is using Fields instead of Parameters just like you did with your **dataSourceExpression**  if that is somthing you have in you main report data.

```
    <subreport>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="91" width="200" height="24"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfInstance})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/report/"+$P{Report1}]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
    <subreport>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="115" width="200" height="27"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfInstance})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/report/"+$P{Report2}]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
    <subreport>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="142" width="200" height="31"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfInstance})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/report/"+$P{Report3}]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply. But here I have set each subreport with different parameter. and also in each sub report I send different-2 list of instance and set value according to that instance. So how can possible to manage that?

Comment: @VivekYadav You can use the *Java API*. For example you can try to use: [*JasperReports API*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) or [*DynamicJasper API*](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/)

Comment: i am sure in the API there is a better way. I think if you were to make the Parameters Generic and use the same name (`$P{Input1}`this can get a bit confusing)  in each of your subreports `<subreportParameter name="Input1">
     <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Report1} =="showInterest.jasper" ? $F{field1}: $P{Report1} =="showWorkExperience.jasper" ? $F{field2}: $F{field3}]]></subreportParameterExpression>`

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have got a better solution using dynamic jasper,generating all subreport dynamically, and pass data from my controller dynamically.